# PEAR Mail problem on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, web-server

I'm having trouble using the [Mail package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) from PEAR. 
I have `PHP Version 5.2.8` installed (`php-fpm` used toghether with `nginx`)

```
$ pear version
PEAR Version: 1.7.2
PHP Version: 5.2.8-1hardy~ppa1

$ pear list
Package          Version State
Mail             1.1.14  stable
...

$ pear config-get php_dir
/usr/share/php

$ ls /usr/share/php/Mail.php
/usr/share/php/Mail.php
```

phpinfo() says:

> include_path   .:/usr/share/php

Everything seems fine, but when I try to

```
require_once "Mail.php";
```

I get:

> Warning: require_once(Mail.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home.. on line 2
>   Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home.. on line 2

Am I missing something?

Comment: following the directions at http://markstechstuff.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-pear-mail-for-php-on-ubuntu.html worked for me, too. apparently, the Mail module of pear is not included in a standard Fedora install. Thanks jGc for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a `open_basedir` issue, which had the path `/usr/share/pear` instead of `/usr/share/php`.

I got it when I tried to `require_once "/usr/share/php/Mail.php"` and got an open_basedir error.

Changing it in `/etc/php5/fpm.conf` solved my problem.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your *php.ini* and look for the paths and directories info. 
Add */usr/share/php/PEAR* to *include_path=*, mine says:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR"
```

Comment: I tried it out. I set the include_path to ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR", but I still get the same error (the path changed).

Comment: Where is the Mail.php file located?

Comment: /usr/share/php/Mail.php

Comment: I finally found out what was causing my error. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar problemo.

I resoved by via http://markstechstuff.blogspot.com/2009/04/installing-pear-mail-for-php-on-ubuntu.html

You may want to change the order of install however. mail seems to depend on the things listed below. My installation process was not smoothe.

But this resolve my Mail.php not being found.